# Can an AppleScript Service discern if selected text is editable?

Tags: macos, applescript, text, services

I have an Automator Service entitled "Calculator" that is comprised of a single *"Run AppleScript"* action. It takes the selected text and then performs a calculation on this input text.

If the selected text is editable, I would like the Service to type the result. If the selected text is uneditable, I would like the Service to communicate the result via a dialog.

I know how to achieve these outcomes in AppleScript. I understand that my goal is entirely feasible if I set up two, separate Services. But, is there a way for my AppleScript-based Service to automatically determine whether the selected text is editable or not, so that I can add an `if <selected text is editable> then` statement?

Comment: You could try to replace the selected text with itself (same as copy/paste). If it works, the text is editable :-)

Comment: I tried playing around with using `try` and `on error` but a _paste_ failure didn't trigger the error with `AXStaticText` although it triggered the _alert sound_. I think you would have to ascertain which app has the text you selected and then determine if one of the properties of the selected text is `AXStaticText` or `AXTextArea`, the latter being editable. Looking at the System Events AppleScript Dictionary, I think that might be doable, although I haven't tried coding it.

Comment: I can't get the copy/paste method to work either. I am unfamiliar with the concept of `AXStaticText`.